# Encoding categorical data 2 different columns

Tags: python, categorical-data, encoding

Suppose I have two columns namely Goods, and Quality which are to be one encoded.

---

> Goods                        Quality  
> Processed Food        A+ grade
>  Canned Food            B grade

---

Does encoding two columns of categorical variables advisable? If so, is placing these columns at the beginning of table advisable or what is the suitable method in case of a prediction model for machine learning.

Comment: What is your end usage ? Exploratory analysis ? Predictions via a machine learning algorithm ?

Comment: Predict via machine learning algorithm

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to add your end usage. I will answer it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use machine-learning algorithms from `scikit-learn` library, then it is not only recommended, but mandatory to convert your data into dummy variables (aka one-hot encoding).

It can be done quite easily using `pandas` library. Just use the function `get_dummies`.

```
import pandas as pd
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'temperature':[30,10,27,24,-6],
                     'feeling':['Hot', 'Cold', 'Hot', 'Hot', 'Cold'],
                     'weather':['Sunny', 'Rainy', 'Rainy', 'Sunny', 'Snowy']})
dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(mydf[['feeling', 'weather']])
pd.concat([mydf[['temperature']],dummy_df], axis = 1)
```

Whether the columns are at the beginning or the end does not change anything.